# In what precise respects are discrete images different from continuous images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Please suggest me how to solution this question

In what precise respects are discrete images different from continuous images?

Comment: Read abut difference between discete signals and continuous signals and sampling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question and I suggest reading about the details in any good textbook on digital image processing, e.g. "Digital Image Processing" by Gonzalez and Woods.

In the following I want to provide a rough overview. The best description of the relationship between a continuous a image and its discrete counterpart is sampling and quantization. Let f(x, y) be a continuous image. Then sampling means to take/sample values at discrete steps (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ... There is a vast body of literature on how to choose these samples. The most important is probably the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). It is often seen as defining the bridge between continuous and discrete signals. After sampling, the taken values are still continuous, i.e. f(x_1, y_1), f(x_2, y_2) ... are continous. Therefore, the next step is quantization - in order to store the values digitally, they are quantized. The quantization strongly depends on the resolution used to store images. In general, 8 bit per color channel is used (e.g. RGB images have 24 bits per pixel). This means that every value f(x_i, y_i) is quantized into one of the 256 values provided by 8 bit quantization. Together, sampling and quanitzation transform a continuous image into a discrete or digital image.

Note that many image processing techniques originate from the continuous image model and can successfully be transferred to the discrete domain (these include simple principles concerning convolution, Fourier analysis, histograms etc.). However, often the discrete model introduces some difficulties one has to be aware of. Among these are quantization errors, sampling issues (e.g. aliasing etc.) and numerical stability.